# Dirt Rally second monitor switch

Tags: dirt-rally

how to switch from laptop monitor to external monitor in **Dirt Rally**?

As its now only works on my native screen...

I tried to look in to the settings but no option found in game settings.

also couldint found any xml configurtation file to set monitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like Dirt Rally only uses the first screen it can find and doesn't offer an option to select another one. Fortunately you *can* change which one it will find first by changing which is your "Main display".

You can do so via right clicking on the desktop and selecting "Screen Resolution". There you'll see a representation of your screens. Select the one you want Dirt to appear on and check "Make this my main display".

This will also change what screen your taskbar shows up on and may rearrange some desktop icons, when you change the setting back (selecting the other screen and checking that ones checkbox) the taskbar will be on the proper screen again, desktop icons *should* be restored to their proper positions but that's not always 100% accurate.